# fopen with const char * from QString not possible

Tags: c++, qt

To dynamically open a FILE I am passing a QString full path.
If passed as a variable, the code fails.
If entered directy (not via a variable) everything works just fine. What is going on here?

```
QString outputfile_qstring("C:/temp/out.mp3");
qDebug()<<"Original output file " << outputfile_qstring;
const char* outputfile = outputfile_qstring.toLatin1().constData();
qDebug()<<"Trying to open output file " << outputfile;
fout = fopen(outputfile, "wb+");
bool fileIsOpen = (fout != 0);
if ( !fileIsOpen ){
    errStr_ = "Error opening the output file " + outputfile_qstring;
    Q_ASSERT(false && "Could not open output file");
    return false;
}
```

The QString to const char * conversion always fails.

```
Original output file  "C:/temp/out.mp3"
Trying to open output file  ????????????????????????aSC,_??r
```

Comment: FILE, fopen, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const char* outputfile = outputfile_qstring.toLatin1().constData();
```

The [`toLAtin1`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1) function returns a [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) *by value*. And since you don't save that object, it will be destructed once the expression is finished, leaving you with `outputfile` being an invalid pointer to non-existing data.

The simple solution is to use the expression `outputfile_qstring.toLatin1().constData()` directly in the call to `fopen`. Or not use `fopen` and the C file functions at all and only use Qt files.

Comment: I agree and thanks for the help. this is a c++ at wrapper around a c library, that's why. Is this the same reason why .toStdString() c_str()   not work either?